# Turning a String into JSX (HTML markup) to display in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, string, jsx

Is there a way to display a string such as: `"<p>Some text</p><strong>A</strong>"` in React.js, as an actual JSX markup and not as a string?

I searched the web for any method for converting a string to HTML, but I've found nothing that could work in React.

**Note** I get the string from the Database and it is generated by a Rich Text Editor.

Comment: JSX is not markup. It is an extension to JavaScript that is transpiled to real JS via Babel before it meets the JS engine.

Comment: Its possible with **`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`**

Comment: const myJsx = '<p>Some text</p><strong>A</strong>'
And in your render: <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: myJsx}}></div>